# AWS Twinmaker with AWS Managed Grafana Tag Query Problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, aws-iot, aws-iot-sitewise

I am working with AWS IoT Twinmaker and AWS Managed Grafana. I am building out a WindFarm scene and I am attempting to update Tag icons based on rules. The documentation seems pretty light in this area and I am following instructions [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-iot-twinmaker-app/tree/main/src/panels/scene-viewer)

Step 5. states:

> In order to see tags change icons based on data: a. Add a "Get Property Value History by Component Type" query to the panel b. Select your component type and property, and optionally a filter on the property value. c. Select Order = DESC to pass data from most recent to oldest to the Scene Viewer. This panel will parse the data and pull off the first value to match with a tag's rule. This assumes you have composed your scene with rules to change tag icons based on data value thresholds.
> Note: The Scene Viewer only supports the "Get Property Value History by Component Type" query

I am seeing the error:

> ValidationException: No dataReaderByComponentType or dataReader connector defined for a query within workspace

I configured the rule on the tag as follows within the scene

[image]

Then I followed the instructions in "Step 5." as just the tag rule didn't seem to work. I then see the error:

[image: ValidationException: No dataReaderByComponentType or dataReader connector defined for a query within workspace]

This is the tag location that should be updated

[image: Tag Location on the scene]

Has anyone encountered this issue? Is there a step that I have missed in the configuration?